# Large header/toolbar above tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-xml, android-toolbar

I've followed this tutorial exactly to get myself a toolbar and tabs:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

However, I now want to change the toolbar so it looks more like this (taken from Google's guidelines):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gzno.png

I want to be able to add more text (and possibly an image) into the toolbar/header. How can I modify the code in the tutorial to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CollapsingToolbar and import another view to add more text or etc. You can find an example from here:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml#L32

You make constant while scolling, do not use behavior attribute:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`